# How to remove a row which contain only missing values in R?

Tags: r

I have a large data set with 11 columns and 100000 rows (for example) in which i have values 1,2,3,4. Where 4 is a missing value. Some of the rows are completely missing. i.e. 4 in all 11 columns. For example

```
"4"  "4"  "4"  "4"  "4"  "4"  "4"  "4"  "4"  "4"   "4"
```

Now what i need is to remove only those rows which are completely missing. In simple words, i want to keep rows with missing value less than 11. I have used na.omit, but it does not work in my case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How one does this will likely depend on information that you haven't provided. Is this a data frame or a matrix? Are the values stored as integers or characters? Try editing your question with the output from running `str(head(foo))` where `foo` is your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A real speedy way would be to use a little bit of math.  Assuming your dataframe is called datf

```
rsum <- rowSums(datf)
datf <- datf[rowSums != 44,] #11 * 4
```

(works for a matrix too)

Comment: I won't give you a minus 1, but this kind of approach is very dangerous.  It works for this specific case, but what happens if you add/delete a column?  Always try and solve problems in robust ways.

Comment: This won't work because a row can sum to 44 without all elements being 4 (e.g. `c(4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,5)`).

Comment: note question... values can only be 1, 2, 3, or 4 in this dataset.

Comment: and, yes, it's not robust but if the author wanted fast sometimes you make a very targeted function for speed... sometimes you have trade off against robustness. (I think it's good that it's lack of robustness was pointed out... now how about cheers for it being really really fast and solving the problem?)

Comment: @John: I agree that sometimes you may want to trade off robustness for speed, but this isn't one of those times because you can have both (see my answer).

Comment: Oh, I think there's plenty of fast solutions Joshua, and there's going to be a continuum between targeted and robust and general...  and I agree your answer is fast and slightly more robust... and it gives a lesson in treating the missing values as special.  In the end though, this is faster. ;)

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps your best option is to utilise R's idiom for working with missing, or `NA` values.  Once you have coded `NA` values you can work with `complete.cases` to easily achieve your objective.

Create some sample data with missing values (i.e. with value 4):

```
set.seed(123)
m <- matrix(sample(1:4, 30, prob=c(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1), replace=TRUE), ncol=6)
m[4, ] <- rep(4, 6)
```

Replace all values equal to 4 with `NA`:

```
m[m==4] <- NA
m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1   NA    2    2    2
[2,]    2    3    3    1    2    3
[3,]    3    2    2    1    2    3
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[5,]   NA    3    1   NA    2    1
```

Now you can use a variety of functions that deal with `NA` values.  For example, `complete.cases` will return only, you guessed it, complete cases:

```
m[complete.cases(m), ]

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    2    3    3    1    2    3
[2,]    3    2    2    1    2    3
```

---

For more information, see `?complete.cases` or `?na.fail` in the `stats` package.

Comment: This is not what is being asked. The OP wants to remove only the rows that are completely missing.

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution elsewhere and am pasting it here using Andrie's code to generate the initial data set.

First generate the data set:

```
set.seed(123)
m <- matrix(sample(1:4, 30, prob=c(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1), replace=TRUE), ncol=6)
m[4, ] <- rep(4, 6)
m[m==4] <- NA
m
```

Here is the intial data set:

```
1    1    NA   2    2    2
2    3    3    1    2    3
3    2    2    1    2    3
NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
NA   3    1    NA   2    1
```

Now remove rows that only contain missing observations:

```
m[rowSums(is.na(m))<ncol(m),]
```

Here is the result:

```
1    1    NA   2    2    2
2    3    3    1    2    3
3    2    2    1    2    3
NA   3    1    NA   2    1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the fastest solution I can think of.  I'll use example data similar to @Andrie.

```
set.seed(21)
m <- matrix(sample(1:6, 110, replace=TRUE), ncol=11)
missVal <- 4
m[4, ] <- rep(missVal, 11)
m <- m[ rowSums((m==missVal)) != NCOL(m), ]
```

The last line works because `m==missVal` returns a matrix of logical (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) values.  `rowSums` converts `TRUE` to 1 and `FALSE` to 0, so in this case we know all the columns are `4` whenever `rowSums` returns 11.

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table` for memory efficiency. The solution creating `is.na(x)` is creating a data set as large as the original, and thus is inefficient.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(m)
missing_value <- 4
missing <- as.data.table(setNames(as.list(rep(4, length(DT)), names(DT))
setkeyv(DT, names(DT))
setkey(missing, names(DT))

DT[-DT[(missing),which=T]]
```

both this and @JoshuaUlrich's solution are fast for large data

```
set.seed(21)
m <- matrix(sample(1:6, 1100000, replace=TRUE), ncol=11)
missVal <- 4
missing_rows <- sample(100000, 53)
m[missing_rows, ] <- rep(missVal, 11)

DT <- as.data.table(m)
setkeyv(DT, names(DT))
missing <- setNames(as.list(rep(missVal, 11)), names(DT))

system.time({DT1 <- DT[-DT[missing,which=T]]})
## user  system elapsed 
## 0.02    0.00    0.01 
system.time({m1 <- m[ rowSums((m==missVal)) != NCOL(m), ]})
## user  system elapsed 
## 0.02    0.02    0.03
```

Comment: Be careful using `T`/`F` instead of `TRUE`/`FALSE`, since `T` and `F` can be re-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick (and should work for both matrices and data.frames):

```
ac<-matrix(c("4","4","4","4","4","4","4","3","3","4","4", rep("4", 11)), nrow=2, ncol=11, byrow=TRUE)

rowsToRemove<-which(apply(ac, 1, function(currow){
    all(currow=="4")
}))
```

Now you can simply do

```
newac<-ac[-rowsToRemove,]
```